# Widespread Swift Protocol for Extensions

Tags: swift, protocols, where-clause, swift-extensions, inout

## Widespread Protocol for Extensions

### Swift 4.1, Xcode 9.3

I was wondering, what are some of the most overarching protocols in Swift. I want to make an extension that applies to values that can be set. The purpose of this was to make it easier to write more one-lined code.

---

#### My Extension:

**Note:** for the time being, the "*overarching*" protocol that I am extending is `Equatable`.

```swift
extension Equatable {
    @discardableResult public func set(to variable: inout Self) -> Self {
        variable = self
        return self
    }
}
```

***Caveat:*** I would like to be able to use `.set(to: )` for values that don't conform to `Equatable` as well.

---

#### Usage:

```swift
let ten = 10
var twenty = 0

(ten + 10).set(to: &twenty)

print(twenty)
// Prints "20"
```

This can be helpful when you need to set and return a value, now only one line of code is required to do so.

```swift
return value.set(to: &variable)
```

---

### Final Question

How do I make `.set(to: )` more far reaching, without needing multiple instances of it?

- For example, if I wrote the same extension for `Equatable`, `CustomStringConvertible`, `CVarArg`, there would be multiple suggestions of the same extensions for many values that conform to all 3 of these protocols.
- If this is not possible, what is the best *overarching* protocol that I can use?

---

**Bonus Question:** is there a way in an extension to do something not dissimilar to `extension Equatable where !(Element: CustomStringConvertible)` or `extension Equatable where !(Element == Int)`  (use the `where` predicate for exclusion purposes)?

---

Comment: Unfortunately I think this isn't possible in current Swift. :-(

Comment: `set(to:)` is a bad name for this. You are not setting the receiver to the parameter, you are setting the parameter to the receiver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, I strong discourage this kind of code. "One-line" code is not generally a goal of Swift. Clear and concise is a goal, with clear winning when they're in conflict. Extending `Any` this way (even if it were legal) is generally a very bad idea since `set(to:)` could easily collide.

But in limited circumstances this may be useful within a single file or for a special use. In that case, it's easily implemented with operators.

```swift
infix operator -->
private func --> <T>(lhs: T, rhs: inout T) -> T {
    rhs = lhs
    return lhs
}

let ten = 10
var twenty = 0

(ten + 10) --> twenty

print(twenty)
// Prints "20"
```

---

The more natural way to do what you're describing is with protocols that you explicitly conform. For example:

```
protocol Settable {}

extension Settable {
    @discardableResult public func set(to variable: inout Self) -> Self {
        variable = self
        return self
    }
}

extension Int: Settable {}
extension String: Settable {}
extension Array: Settable {}
extension Optional: Settable {}
```

You can attach `Settable` to any types that are useful for this purpose, and these extensions can be provided anywhere in the project (even in other modules). There is no way to attach a method to every possible type in Swift.

Comment: Is there no way I can do the same thing as this with dot notation and extension rather than with operators?

Comment: Yes; use a protocol and explicitly conform the types you find useful. There is no way to extend `Any` (and I believe this is not an accident; I don't expect that to be added in the future).